# Htaccess redirect from '/%postname%.html' to '/%postname%'

Tags: redirect, htaccess

I have a Drupal 5.x based travel review site which I'm moving over to Wordpress 3.x (same domain name).

The Drupal site is structured like this:

- `www.example.com/travel-guides` (these are top-level pages) - these
  are only a handful.
- `www.example.com/<filename>.html` (filename is the name of a place / attraction etc). - makes up for bulk of the content in the site.

In WordPress the setup is fairly straightforward. All content follows a simple permalink:

```
www.example.com/postname
```

How do I set a rule in .htaccess to bulk redirect all the pages? There are over 600 pages and I don't want to manually set redirect rules for all of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Above the WordPress rewrite rules add:

```
RedirectMatch permanent ^/([^/]+)\.html$ /$1
```

That will catch `example.com/foo.html` but not `example.com/travel-guides/foo.html`. To catch all URLs ending with `.html` remove the first `^` from the pattern.

To redirect all URLs ending with `.html` except those in `travel-guides` you need mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/travel-guides/
RewriteRule ([^/]+)\.html$  /$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks toscho. Will implement that. But how do I set redirects for URLs within a folder but not example.com/travel-guides/foo.html. I'm not too familiar with coding but usually follow DIY guides. So this would be a 301 redirect right?

Comment: @user10718 See my update. Both rules send a 301.