# Wordpress permalink change causes all incoming links to give 404 errors

Tags: permalinks, 404-error

My site URL is http://funandfoodcafe.com
I changed my Permalink structure to Postname today, and I am using WP 3.5.

All the links on the site redirect to the new structure correctly, but all incoming links, from Google or any other referring sites still go to "http://funandfoodcafe.com/post-name.html" instead of "http://funandfoodcafe.com/post-name/"

The extra .html is causing all incoming links to result in 404 errors. I get heavy referral traffic, so this is really bad, because its almost like my site is down!

Can someone help me resolve this issue please?

Thanks,
Mansi

Comment: what did you expect to happen exactly? change it back until you put a solution in place.

Comment: how can I redirect all links with .html extension to go to just postname/ e.g: http://www.funandfoodcafe.com/melting-crayons.html should actually go to http://www.funandfoodcafe.com/melting-crayons/

Comment: the simplest solution to this is done via an .htaccess file, not within WordPress. see [this question/answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69885/htaccess-redirect-from-postname-html-to-postname).

Answer (score 1):

In your `.htaccess` file put:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
```

That should redirect with a "moved permaently" from the .html pages to pages with the endings stripped. It should probably go above your WordPress rules. It should even preserve query strings-- at least it did when I tested it.

Comment: Aah! thanks so much ha_dum, that worked. I needed to add another redirect statement to my .htaccess too, for some other links that were not being redirected by using WP alone, so I added these 3 lines to my .htaccess file: "RedirectMatch 301 ^/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/(.*)$ http://funandfoodcafe.com/$3
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} \.html$
RewriteRule (.*).html$ /$1/ [R=301,L]"   and looks liek its working for now...will test some more and let you know how it goes!